# I'm pulling data with React Native axios. I can see the data I've captured on the console screen. But I can't show in app. Can you help me?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

I'm pulling data with React Native axios. I can see the data I've captured on the console screen. But I can't show in app. Can you help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxLne.png)
**Response datas: "saat" and "vakit"**

Comment: Can you post the response that gets logged to the console right after your axios request?

Comment: {
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "saat": "04:57",
      "vakit": "İmsak"
    },
    {
      "saat": "06:26",
      "vakit": "Güneş"
    },
    {
      "saat": "13:09",
      "vakit": "Öğle"
    },
    {
      "saat": "16:47",
      "vakit": "İkindi"
    },
    {
      "saat": "19:40",
      "vakit": "Akşam"
    },
    {
      "saat": "21:04",
      "vakit": "Yatsı"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for `{datas.result.saat}`.  But your response is not in this format.  `datas.result` is an array of objects with keys `saat` and `vakit`.  I'm not sure which of the results you're interested, but you could display the first result with `{datas.result[0].saat}`.  You can read more here about accessing arrays by index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array